# How to get the original text using $text at the same time rule returns value

Tags: antlr

So I have the following grammar:

```
top_cmd :cmds
        {
            std::cout << $cmds.text << std::endl;
        }
        ;


cmds returns [char* str]
    : cmd+
    {
        str = new char('a');
    }
    ;
```

I get g++ compile error:

```
"str" was not declared in this scope
```

If I remove this line

```
std::cout << $cmds.text << std::endl;
```

Then compile is fine.

I googled how "$text" is used, it seems to me it is expected to use $text for the purpose of rewrite rules. In my example, the function "cmds" returns "char*" when I remove the offending line and some complex structure when I keep it.

I can think of the following workaround:

```
1. do not have lower level rules return anything, but pass variable into lower level rules.
2. use re-write rules
```

But both are pretty big change(my real project is fairly large) considering how much time budge I have.

So is there a short-cut? Basically I do not want to change the grammar of top_cmd and cmds, but I can get the full text of cmds' matching.

I am using ANTLR3C, but I believe this is independent of target language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do something like this:

```
top_cmd :cmds
    {
        std::cout << $cmds.text << std::endl;}
    ;


cmds returns [char* str]
: cmd+
  {
      $str = new char('a'); //added $
  }
  ;
```

`$cmds.text` will return the text matched for the rule cmds. If you want to return the str, you should change it for `$cmds.str`

> $text: The text matched for a rule or the text matched
>              from the start of the rule up until the point of
>             the $text expression evaluation. Note that this
>            includes the text for all tokens including those
>           on hidden channels, which is what you want
>          because usually that has all the whitespace and
>         comments. When referring to the current rule,
>        this attribute is available in any action including
>       any exception actions.

from [the Definitive Antrl reference](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http://www.zenisoft.cn/calibre/get/pdf/1321&ei=hIgKU9CgJKTv0QG624DgAQ&usg=AFQjCNG4EnLj9BAYNV0M1mkVzaatOe7Qnw&sig2=2tE_0vH5x17VYeEsdnJ-Qg&bvm=bv.61725948,d.dmQ&cad=rja)

Comment: Yes, that is it, thanks!  I am actually a bit confused, what is the meaning of prefixing '$' to 'str'?

Comment: @my_question `str` is not a variable reference. It is merely a coincidence that the generated code created a variable named `str` in scope and happened to work. `$str` is a proper reference in ANTLR syntax (to a parameter, return value, label, or rule/token reference), so even if the generated code named the variable `str__GEN__` it would reference the correct variable in the assignment.